# Table is not created in java-mySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I used mySQL workbench to create a database named testdb. Then I connect to it by Database>Connect to Database. Then I write some code in java (eclipse) to

1. Get connection to database
2. Create a table in the database.

The output of code shows that the connection and create table is done.

But When I return to mySQL, I don't see any table in the database. Can anyone help me about why table isn't created?

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getConnection();
        createTable();
    }

    public static void createTable() throws Exception {
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement create = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first varchar(255), last varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id)");
            create.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
        finally {
            System.out.println("Function complete.");
            };

    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{

        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "00000";
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            return conn;
        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

        return null;    
        }


}
```

Here is the output:

Connected

Connected

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Function complete.

Comment: Please don't add information as comments but add them to your question via an [edit]

Comment: *"Can anyone help me about why table isn't created?"*  Can be alot off things... 1) Not connected to the database.. 2) Not selected a default (working) database with `USE database_name` should also be possible with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_name.tablename` 3) The used MySQL user does not have CREATE privilege..

Comment: Do you realize that you're creating 2 connections in your `main()`?

Comment: Didn't you miss a bracket at the end of the statement? :)

Comment: The complete code seams a bit wierd.. @Thomas `getConnection()` should be called as `main.getConnection()` .. i could be wrong as didn't do Java for years..

Comment: @RaymondNijland no `getConnection()` is fine, it's just that it's called in `main()` _and_ in `createTable()` - that shouldn't be the problem though. It's more of a side note like me asking the OP why `getConnection()` and `createTable()` have `throws Exception` if they catch all exceptions :)

Comment: i know (to) many programming languages then you start mixing things up somethings @Thomas some don't like it when used like that you explicitly need to use static calling.. i didn't know for sure annymore if Java also required that or not that's why the code seamed a bit wierd

Comment: *"Do you realize that you're creating 2 connections in your main()? "* indeed @Thomas , topicstarter should ideally read about [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) as database connections could/should be reused..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your help. I use  "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'root'@'localhost';" command in mysql shell, but still it doesn't create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parenthesis `)` is missing in your sql statement，the correct is

```
 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, first varchar(255), last varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id))"
```